# I can't get ipython console to play a sound in spyder

Tags: python, ipython, spyder, playback

I've been trying to play audio files (.wav) using IPython but I don't hear any sound.

What do I do to hear the actual sound?

Here is the code:

```
import IPython
IPython.display.Audio("180960__kleeb__gunshot.wav")
```

I expect to hear a sound but I only get this result:

```
Out[46]: <IPython.lib.display.Audio object>.
```

Comment: All I get is: Out[46]: <IPython.lib.display.Audio object>.

Comment: I have also tried the wave.make_audio() and I get the same result

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Our IPython console can't handle this type of content, sorry.

Comment: Alternatives to `IPython.display.Audio` used in Jupyter: [Playing and Recording Sound in Python](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/). I use [python-sounddevice](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#python-sounddevice). It depends on `PortAudio` and can be installed with conda directly (conda-forge), without using Windows pre-built versions mentioned in the [documentation](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.8/).

Answer (score 4):

You need a front-end notebook that can support those widgets. I don't think you can do it with IPython interactive shell.

> The IPython Notebook is now known as the Jupyter Notebook.

Tried with Jupyter notebook and it works perfectly:
[image]

If you want to try out Jupyter, you can do it [here](https://jupyter.org/try).